# Generic type definition syntax on F#

Tags: f#

This is not a big deal, but is there any way in F# to get a generic type definition without calling GetGenericTypeDefinition() ? `IComparable<_>` is `IComparable<object>` (or whatever type is inferred) and `IComparable<>` is a syntax error.

VB.NET

```
GetType(IComparable(Of ))
```

C#

```
typeof(IComparable<>)
```

F#

```
typeof<IComparable<_>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

Comment: Note that it is "a big deal" in the rare case that you need to use this as a System.Type argument to an attribute.  "[<MyAttr(typeof<list<int>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition())>]" is obviously not allowed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want "typedefof"

```
printfn "%s" (typedefof<list<int>>).Name
```

Comment: Hopefully the somewhere was my blog!  http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!725.entry