# F# equivalent of the C# typeof(IEnumerable<>)

Tags: reflection, f#, c#-to-f#

I have a piece of code where I need to figure out if a given type implements `IEnumerable<T>` (I don't care about the T)

I've tried (`t:System.Type` in case you wonder)

```
let interfaces = t.GetInterfaces()
let enumerbale = 
    interfaces.Any(fun t -> 
        t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typeof<IEnumerable<>>
    )
```

however that won't compile (the compile doesn't like the <>). I then tried

```
let interfaces = t.GetInterfaces()
let enumerbale = 
    interfaces.Any(fun t -> 
        t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typeof<IEnumerable<'a>>
    )
```

but get's a warning that 'a is constraint to obj. I Don't want to figure out if `IEnumerable<obj>` is implemented but `IEnumerabl<>`.

Any one know's the solution and btw feel free to comment on the code above as well.

Comment: I would be remiss not to point out that this question is one of many whose answers are found in [What does this C# code look like in F#?](http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/28/what-does-this-c-code-look-like-in-f-part-one-expressions-and-statements/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652050/generic-type-definition-syntax-on-f

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This should work:

```
typedefof<System.IEnumerable<_>>
```

**EDIT**

As Tomas notes, there's nothing special about the `_` wildcard here; F# infers that the type `obj` is the most general applicable type in this context, so this is the same as using `typedefof<System.IEnumerable<obj>>`.  In some cases the way this works can be a bit of a hindrance, though.  For instance, if you define an interface `type I<'a when 'a :> I<'a>> = interface end`, then you can't use `typedefof<I<_>>`, because `I<obj>` doesn't satisfy the generic constraint and F# can't infer another more appropriate type.  This can happen even without recursive constraints (e.g. `type I<'a when 'a : struct and 'a :> System.ICloneable> = interface end`.  This is in contrast to C#'s approach, which works perfectly fine in the analogous cases.

As to your code itself, I think you'll want to make some other changes, too, such as ensuring that the interface is generic before calling `GetGenericTypeDefinition`.  Here's how I'd write the test function:

```
(fun t -> t.IsGenericType && (t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<_ seq>))
```

Comment: Your solution saved me from another problem :) with not so helpful errormessage "unsupported due to the current State of the object" which is a Way of saying can't Call getgenerictypedefinition ón a non generic type

Comment: this becomes insanely ugly, if generic type is constrained. In my case the constraint is `when 'T: struct and 'T :> Enum`, so the compiler complains about `_`:

`Error FS0071 Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'int' for a type inference variable. The type 'int' is not compatible with the type 'Enum' Consider adding further type constraints.`

Answer (score 21):

As far as I know, F# doesn't have any equivalent to C#'s `typeof(IEnumerable<>)`. This is because, this is a special syntax supported explicitly by C#. In F#, `typeof` is a normal function and the type argument needs to be a fully specified type. You can get a generic type definition programatically like this:

```
let t = typeof<IEnumerable<obj>>
let genericT = t.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

The problem with your solution with `IEnumerable<'a>` is that the F# compiler still needs to find some concrete type to use (as generic type definition isn't a valid type). If the type inference deduces that the type parameter isn't restricted in any way, it uses default type, which is `obj`.

**EDIT** I didn't know about `typedefof<IEnumerable<_>>`, that is very useful! Anyway, note that the underscore doesn't have any special meaning here - the actual type argument is still `IEnumerable<obj>`, but the `typedefof` function calls `GetGenericTypeDefinition` behind the scene.